# How to solve the error (?memory related) on navigating between view controllers

Tags: ios, memory-management, uinavigationcontroller, nsarray, nsobject

I have two view controllers (CreateReport & ViewReport). and an NSObject class (PDFRenderer).

The infoArray(NSMutableArray)is declared as extern in PDFRenderer(NSObject class) & accessed by import # PDFRenderer.h in CreateReport class. The user selects tableview rows desired and passess the selected items to infoArray(NSMutableArray) and push ViewReport class on navigation stack to view the pdf generated using the items in the array.

CreateReport--(PDFRenderer)-->ViewReport

PROBLEM: After viewing the pdf first time without problem - now I want to navigate back to CreateReport from ViewReport - select or deselect desired table cells - update the infoArray - and push ViewReport class to see the pdf regenerated with items in updated infoArray - I am unable to pass any new changes to the infoArray(NSMutableArray). I am guessing the array is getting released or there is some memory problem. Can some one help me with this?

```
 CreateReport.m

#import "ViewReport.h"
#import "PDFRenderer.h"

-(void)preparePDF{

 //self.draftArrray has data for CreateReport tableView cells and gets updated on tableView Cells selection

NSDictionary*id_dict=[self.draftArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray* id_arr= [id_dict objectForKey:@"Rows"];
NSMutableArray*id_array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];    
id_arr= [id_dict objectForKey:@"Rows"];
NSDictionary*dict=[[NSDictionary alloc]init];
for (dict in id_arr) {
    NSString*id_string=[dict objectForKey:@"title"];
    [id_array addObject:id_string];
    }
 infoArray=id_array; //pass id_array to infoArray declared in PDFRenderer
 }
-(void)IBAction{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"finalViewReport" sender:self];
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"finalViewReport"]) {
      //ViewReport*destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
       [self preparePDF];
        }
}
```

-*-
    PDFRenderer.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

extern  NSMutableArray*infoArray;


@interface PDFRenderer : NSObject 

@property (nonatomic,strong,retain) NSMutableArray*infoArray;


+ (PDFRenderer *)sharedInstance;
```

-*-

```
 PDFRenderer.m

#import "PDFRenderer.h"

NSMutableArray*infoArray;

@implementation PDFRenderer


@synthesize infoArray;


+(PDFRenderer*) sharedInstance{
    static PDFRenderer* _shared = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    _shared = [[self alloc] init];
    _shared.infoArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

});
return _shared;
 }


+ (void)drawPageNumber:(NSInteger)pageNum
{
NSString *pageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page %d", pageNum];
UIFont *theFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(612, 72);

CGSize pageStringSize = [pageString sizeWithFont:theFont
                               constrainedToSize:maxSize
                                   lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByClipping];
CGRect stringRect = CGRectMake(((612.0 - pageStringSize.width) / 2.0),
                               720.0 + ((72.0 - pageStringSize.height) / 2.0),
                               pageStringSize.width,
                               pageStringSize.height);
[pageString drawInRect:stringRect withFont:theFont];
}


+(void)drawPDF:(NSString*)fileName
{
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(fileName, CGRectZero, nil);
NSInteger currentPage = 0;
BOOL done = NO;
  do {
   for ( int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++ )
   {
// Mark the beginning of a new page.

UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 792), nil);

   // Draw a page number at the bottom of each page.
   currentPage++;
   [self drawPageNumber:currentPage];

//[self drawText:@"Hello World" inFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 50)];

       int  xOrigin= 50;
       int  yOrigin= 50;
       int rowHeight = 50;
       int columnWidth = 512;

       int numberOfRows = 7;
       int numberOfColumns = 1;
if (!i>0) {
[self drawLabels];

  xOrigin= 50;
  yOrigin= 300;

CGPoint from = CGPointMake(10, 60);
CGPoint to = CGPointMake(602, 60);
[PDFRenderer drawLineFromPoint:from toPoint:to];

CGPoint from1 = CGPointMake(10, 140);
CGPoint to1 = CGPointMake(602, 140);
[PDFRenderer drawLineFromPoint:from1 toPoint:to1];
}

  UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

}


+(void)drawLabels
 {

int i;
NSString*s=[[NSString alloc]init];
int x=20;
int y=47;
for (i=0;i<infoArray.count;i++) {
    if (i==0|i==3|i==6|i==9|i==12|i==15) {
        x=20;
        y+=15;
    }
    s=[infoArray objectAtIndex:i];
   [self drawText:s inFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 100, 25)];
    x+=185;
    y+=0;
}
}
```

-*-

```
 ViewReport.m

-(void)viewDidLoad
{

  NSString* fileName = [self getPDFFileName];
 [PDFRenderer drawPDF:fileName];


  NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileName];
  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
  [detailview setScalesPageToFit:YES]; //UIWebView*detailview
 [detailview loadRequest:request];
//[self.view addSubview:detailview];

}

-(NSString*)getPDFFileName
{
NSString* fileName = @"newReport.PDF";
NSArray *arrayPaths =
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                    NSDocumentDirectory,
                                    NSUserDomainMask,
                                    YES);
NSString *path = [arrayPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* pdfFileName = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

return pdfFileName;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line `NSMutableArray*infoArray;` Since you are using `@synthesise` you don't need this one.

Also, I don't see where you are using this array after all?

Comment: I have added some more code where the array is being used. If I remove NSMutableArray*infoArray as you suggested - I get Apple-Mach O Linker error.- I get error.                                                   Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_infoArray", referenced from:
      -[ViewReport viewDidLoad] in ViewReport.o
      +[PDFRenderer drawLabels] in PDFRenderer.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Any more suggestions?? Also I am suspecting the original array (draftArray - used to display table view of CreateReport) from which the infoArray is obtained is getting released on moving back and forth from CreateReport to ViewReport. I want to be able to move back and forth from CreateReport to ViewReport and be able to update the infoArray from draftArray as table rows selected, thus generating PDF file using infoArray.